# Linq with DbNull values

Tags: linq

I have a DataTable that contains columns that would contain DbNull values.  I want to use Linq and output a new DataTable but I want the DbNull values to be perserved.  Here is an example:

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("C1",System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("C2",System.Type.GetType("System.String")));
        DataRow row;
        row = dt.NewRow();
        row["C1"] = "Hello";
        row["C2"] = "World";
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
        row = dt.NewRow();
        row["C1"] = DBNull.Value;
        row["C2"] = "World";
        dt.Rows.Add(row);

        var cars1 = from car in dt.AsEnumerable()
                    where car.Field<String>("C2") == "World"
                    select car;
        DataTable cars2 = cars1.CopyToDataTable();
```

How can the C1 column of the second row have the DbNull value be perserved in cars2 DataTable?

Comment: It **is** persisted... just try, you will see that "C1" in the second row of cars2 is still DBNull.Value

Comment: BTW, you don't need to write `System.Type.GetType("System.String")` : you can just do `typeof(String)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thomas is correct - `CopyToDataTable()` does nothing special to `DBNull` field values. However, the `Field<T>` extension method on `DataRow` does return `null` for `DBNull` - were you using that to test `cars2`?